# SSAS 2014 and Teradata 14.10

Tags: ssas

I am trying to build an SSAS 2014 cube using Teradata 14.10 as the relational back end. I am using the .net driver to connect to the database and have set the response buffer size to 65477

I notice that the cube builds extremely slowly and one of the reason for this is of course the sheer amount of data being returned. The query itself executes extremely fast. Its the data transfer which takes hours.

Are there any any tips to improve the build time? Has someone else done this with maybe tweaking some settings or using some other method to improve the response time for the data transfer?

Comment: Have you partitioned your measure groups? Is it enterprise edition SSAS?

Comment: Yes they are partitioned to the max its possible with the dimensions. Can't partition it further. The max number of rows being loaded into certain partitions are 40 million. But majority are 20million or less.

Comment: then it is fair to say you have Enterprise edition if you have that many partitions. How many partitions? How many cores on the SSAS server? How long does processing one average size partition take? How long after you start it processing in SSMS does it take before any rows start being received?

Comment: Also if you monitor the processing dialog in SSMS what percentage of time is spent reading from Teradata and then what time is spent on building aggregations and indexes after all the rows are read?